# Unable to change the value of a attribute in template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a very peculiar situation.  My demo **directive** is

```
.directive('sampleanchortag',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'EA',
        //replace:true,//
        template:'<a href="https://www.google.com">Click Here</a>',
        link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
            elem.attr('href','https://www.gmail.com'); //works when set replace=true
        }
    };
});
```

By default I am setting the value of href to a **url** within the template & in **link** function I am changing the value of href to a different **url**.
However,I am not able to do so without setting **repalce=true**.  After setting **replace=true** I could easily change the value of **template's href** using elem.attr('href',mynewurl).

**replace=true** is depreciated in latest version of angular as per this
[AngularJs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Kindly let me know where I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you change attr with you code(without replace):

```
elem.attr('href','https://www.gmail.com'); //elem is sampleanchortag not anchor element
```

Then your html structure will become:

```
<sampleanchortag href="https://www.gmail.com">
    <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
</sampleanchortag>
```

If you don't want to replace your directive element, then you need to change your code into this:

```
elem.find("a").attr('href', 'https://www.gmail.com');
```

[Here is JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/o0ht1f3k/)

By the way, I think gmail's address is mail.google.com  : )